# Picklist value in picklist not found

Tags: deployment, picklist

I am trying to deploy picklist value Pupils and Students from Development to Integration environment but end up getting below error:

> [RecordType Account.GL_Indirect_Account] Picklist value: Pupils and Students in picklist: GL_Target_Group__c not found

Can someone please provide some inputs

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you've included the field definition file for `GL_Target_Group__c` that includes this new value, and if that field depends on a [GlobalValueSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalvalueset.htm), make sure it is updated, and that you deploy that as well.